# FT_Read function Buffer

Tags: c, embedded, ftdi

I'm attempting to use the [DX22](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/ProgramGuides/D2XX_Programmer's_Guide(FT_000071).pdf) library and a FTDI USB-UART to interact with an NXP chip.  I'm having issues creating a buffer in C, which grabs all available data, appends it to a string, then proceeds with the program.  All data coming from the NXP chip should end with "CR LF".  Should I create a function to search the incoming data and construct a string, terminating at the "CR LF"?

```
while (FT_Read != FT_OK)
    {
    if (RxBytes > 0) {
        FT_status = FT_Read(handle, RxBuffer, RxBytes, &BytesReceived);
        if (FT_status == FT_OK) {
            printf("RX: %s\n", RxBuffer);
        }
        else {
            printf("RX buffer empty.\n");
        }

    }
    else {
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, yes, but the CR and LF may arrive in separate Read calls, so you have to allow for that.  It's not uncommon to use a byte-by-byte state-machine to handle protocols over streaming links lile serial/TCP.

Note:

printf("RX: %s\n", RxBuffer);

assumes that the buffer contains are a null-terminated string.  That is unlikely in general, so use 'BytesReceived' as an index  to insert a null at the end of the data, and make sure that the buffer always contains enough space for it.